# Maximum number of code lines in a JS function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I have a very big function in my JS code with about 108000 lines of code.
I have an error, but if I decrease the number of lines, no error.

So the number of lines code is limited.

Do you know a way to increase the limit ?
I work on IE9.

Thanks
Bob

Comment: It's probably just an error on in one of those lines that you removed. Else, try using JSMin or packer [http://dean.edwards.name/packer/]

Comment: No it's not ... when I slip into 2 functions that works.

Comment: Can you minify your JS file to make it smaller or split it in some smaller files?

Comment: Try another browser (Chrome, Firefox)...

Comment: I don't want to minimize of split it. I need this big code ... And I need it in IE9 also.

Comment: Can you try by following this: http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.scripting.jscript/browse_thread/thread/fcb104c0dbd08fbe/49ce2e37e7e980c6?q=32768&lnk=ol& by inserting a dummy function function IEFix(){} every 30.000 lines...

Comment: I'd love to know why you think you need 108,000 lines in one function. If I got to 100 lines in a single function I'd probably think I was doing something wrong. What on earth does your function do?

Comment: Probably the function is generated. Perhaps adding some more RAM to your machine could help. I won't be surprised if the JIT compiler inside the browser has some worse-than-linear algorithms (eg. *O (n log n)* or *O (n^2)* where *n* is the number of instructions. FWIW, experimentally, the GCC compiler (when optimizing with `-O1`) has a nearly quadratic complexity (w.r.t. function size).

Comment: It might not be enough. For instance, 8Gbytes of RAM is not really enough for GCC to compile a single 100KLOC function with optimization.

Comment: Guys, this is actually a legitimate question. Just because it smells of bad practice doesn't make it any less valid.

Comment: 108k lines of method code?  ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 3):

Can you try by following this:
http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.scripting.jscript/browse_thread/thread/fcb104c0dbd08fbe/49ce2e37e7e980c6?q=32768&lnk=ol&

a little old (2007 and IE7), but there is a good explaination about it.

It seems that you can insert a dummy function `function IEFix(){}` every 30.000 lines to break your scope definition.

But, please, think about to reduce your payload and split your code in many maintainable JS files.